# Sencha Touch: lags during animation (carousel)

Tags: sencha-touch

I have an application with few "pages" with images. When i use carousel for changing "pages" - it lags. And i can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your browser is choking on the cpu-intensive CSS3 features involved in the carousel. They are supposed to be hardware accelerated (done on the GPU), but only certain platforms support this (iOS yes, Android not yet IIRC).

See this talk from SenchaCon 2010 on performance: http://vimeo.com/17882927